# Sharepoint lookup value from list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a very locked down Sharepoint environment where I can use only the Sharepoint Designer or the Sharepoint web interface. I cannot deploy code.

I have list A and list B. User Robert starts a workflow from list A and I need to populate the workflow email with a value from list B (lookup user Robert in List B and give me the ID value).

Is there a way to do that in a constrained environment such as the one I'm using?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used AJAX in the past to query a separate list on page load, though I can't find the code at the moment. There are several web services exposed by SharePoint that allow querying and [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/05/06/querying-sharepoint-list-items-using-jquery.aspx) seems to offer a solution that may be able to be adapted, using SOAP and jQuery. If I can find the time and the code, I'll happily post what I can soon.

**EDIT:** Workflow notifications can have links to the item being created or modified (whatever triggered the email) - If you have not seen this page: [Send e-mail in a workflow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx), then it contains instructions for several modifications, including links to the item. With Sharepoint Designer, you can modify the View-Item page for items in that list so that they display other information related to the item, such as Richard's information.

Comment: Thanks CJ, this could be a viable solution for many scenarios but I think email is a little different. I cannot launch a webservice from within the workflow email. Could you think of some other approach I could use?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to insert data from List B (based upon an item in List A) into the workflow email sent by the server. I'm not sure how to do this (if it is possible), but more information would be useful. What is the goal of inserting the data (that is, getting Robert's ID)? Would a landing page that shows the information you want be acceptable? What browsers and email clients must be supported?

Comment: Concerning the possibility of a landing page, also consider the regulatory implications of what you are trying to inject into the email. If this is a military or government system, my experience is that emails should be simply a notification such as "There is new information available through your account on System XYZ" and cannot provide or contain links, PII, or instructions/orders/commands (this is due to lack of encryption and/or a digital signature on the email).

Comment: Hi CJ, thanks for your answers. You understood the problem correctly. I'm trying to get Robert's ID in the email to build a link. Any workaround (including a landing page that displays the information) would be acceptable. It isn't a military site anyway. Just some big paranoid corporation :)

Comment: Alright - unfortunately, a complete discussion of how to implement a landing page is not possible here - and digresses from the original question. I don't think the injection is possible with only SharePoint Designer and the web interface. AFAIK, it would require server-side code.

Comment: ## Many methods for a landing page ## One is that it could be statically linked and use a list webpart set to filter based on the user viewing the list (like 'applies to'). Further filtering could be based upon category, how old the item is (date), or completion status (yes/no), etc... combining lists in a list view or web part is supported natively (at least to the degree I think you need). In fact, the link I edited in above might offer help with half the process (making a link to the item to create a landing page)

Comment: Gotcha, CJ. Thanks for helping. I'll report here if this approach worked.